# How to require for a ruby script in osx automator?

Tags: ruby, macos, shell, automator

I'm trying to run a ruby  script in the mac automator. First of all, I chosen "Run Shell script" and in the drop down for that I choose /bin/zsh instead of /usr/bin/ruby, beacuse I want to run ruby 2.3.0 and not whatever version there was in /usr/bin/ruby.

```
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby /Users/me/Projects/Private/SubSeeker/main.rb $1
```

This is how the automator script looks like, and it runs well till that point I have to require something. For example when I require rest-client, I do it like this: `require 'rest-client'` but for some reason that doesn't work. I get this error:

```
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- rest-client (LoadError)
from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/me/Projects/Private/SubSeeker/scraper.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/me/Projects/Private/SubSeeker/main.rb:4:in `require_relative'
from /Users/me/Projects/Private/SubSeeker/main.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

The gem is installed and I can use the script when not running through automator.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: are you sure the gem is installed with ruby-2.3.0 and not the system ruby?

Comment: No, I'm not, how can I check if it is? I now that when running the script in the terminal, I'm using ruby 2.3.0.

Comment: @ptierno , sorry, forgot to mention..